# Loading files from JAR in Scala

Tags: scala, jar

I have the following code structure:

```
Projects/
     classes/
         performance/AcPerformance.class
         resources/
                  Aircraft/
                          allAircraft.txt
```

I have the contents of the classes folder in a JAR and my AcPerformance scala code is trying to read the contents of the Aircraft folder text files. My code:

```
val AircraftPerf = getClass.getResource("resources/Aircraft").getFile
val dataDir = new File(AircraftPerf)
val acFile = new File(dataDir, "allAircraft.txt")

for (line <- linesFromResource(acFile)) {
  // read in lines
}
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\file:\C:\Projects\libraries\aircraft.jar!\Aircraft\allAircraft.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Is this the correct way to read the contents of a JAR? THanks!

Answer (score 10):

No, `URL`'s `getFile` isn't going to do what you want here—the path it gives you isn't a file system path that you could use in a `File` constructor. You'd be best off using `getResourceAsStream` and the full path to the resource:

```
val in = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/Aircraft/allAircraft.txt")
```

Note that you also need to preface the path with `/` to make it absolute—in your current version you're looking for a `resources` directory under `performance`.